# add a second (multiple) owner / user for a folder (website folder)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, users, ftp

Im using Plesk 17 and Ubuntu 16, Plesk automatically created an ftp user for my "webspace".
I won't give this created user more rights and can't change it easy to my main user withouth messing up everything.

I connect with my main user with a ssh key to the server. I don't allow other users to connect via ssh.

Now if i would connect with bitvise and Dreamweaver i get permission denied, because the owner is the created user by Plesk (dexxxxxx - img).

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Gqyza]

How i can add a second user withouth changeing the existing groups for this folder ?

I tried to create a group added both users, but like that all other groups get replaced (psacln, root, psaserv -> siteaccess group)

If i replace the user created by plesk the Homepage outputs access denied.

Edit: I tried to add the main user to the same groups like dexxx then i can see the folder but cant write into it. (dexxx can)

Comment: With the Plex user instead of `debian-transmission` and whichever directory it's using instead of `/opt/www`

Comment: @muru im using ubuntu and don't have acl installed.

Comment: The commands are in the `acl` package. Install it, since the ext4 filesystems have ACLs enabled anyway.